# Parallelizing / Multithreading with data.table

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, data.table

I have a large data with more than 1 billion observations, and I need to perform some string operations which is slow.

My code is as simple as this:

```
DT[, var := some_function(var2)]
```

If I'm not mistaken, `data.table` uses multithread when it is called with `by`, and I'm trying to parallelize this operation utilizing this. To do so, I can make an interim grouper variable, such as

```
DT[, grouper := .I %/% 100]
```

and do

```
DT[, var := some_function(var2), by = grouper]
```

I tried some benchmarking with a small sample of data, but surprisingly I did not see a performance improvement. So my questions are:

1. Does `data.table` use multithreading when it's used with `by`?
2. If so, is there a condition that multithreading is enabled / disabled?
3. Is there a way that user can "enforce" `data.table` to use multithreading here?

FYI, I see that multithreading enabled with half of my cores when I import data.table, so I guess there's no openMP issue here.

Comment: Perhaps, you will get some more details on the inner workings with `verbose = TRUE`.

Comment: Not a specialist, but you can set the number of threads with `setDTthreads(threads = 0)` ("0" means that all threads are used; you can also specifying a precise number of threads). And  if you want to check the number of threads in use : `getDTthreads()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got answers from `data.table` developers from [data.table github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5200).

Here's a summary:

- Finding groups of `by` variable itself is parallelized always, but more importantly,
- If the function on `j` is generic (User Defined Function) then there's no parallelization.
- Operations on `j` is parallelized if the function is [(gforce) optimized](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/datatable.optimize) (Expressions in j which contain only the functions `min`, `max`, `mean`, `median`, `var`, `sd`, `sum`, `prod`, `first`, `last`, `head`, `tail`)

So, it is advised to do parallel operation manually if the function on `j` is generic, but it may not always guarantee speed gain. [Reference](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3962)

**==Solution==**

In my case, I encountered vector memory exhaust when I plainly used `DT[, var := some_function(var2)]` even though my server had 1TB of ram, while data was taking 200GB of memory.

I used `split(DT, by='grouper')` to split my `data.table` into chunks, and utilized `doFuture` `foreach` `%dopar%` to do the job. It was pretty fast.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very instructive feedback @Matthew Son